# How can I implement dropdown with Icons using html bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap but can you please give an idea on how to implement this type of dropdown? Thank you

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InwLB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Mark up for such a drop down

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="icon"><span
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>User Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Css for the drop down

```
.dropdown-menu a.icon {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.dropdown-menu a.icon .glyphicon {
  top: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

The key is that glyphicons are absolute-positioned, and even though they are "contained" inside the  in the markup, the positioning is relative to the entire menu by default. By adding the .icon class to each menu anchor that contains an icon, it allows you to make the positioning relative to that anchor, and also pad the anchor text so that the icon has room to show properly.

Comment: I checked your answer but it looks like this will submit whenever I choose an option.  What I need is I am free to choose one of the options before submit